# Administrator option is disabled for domain accounts in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, sudo, active-directory, administrator, sssd

I am the domain admin. My domain account in my system have administrator option disabled. I have tried adding the user to sudoers. That didn't work. Any other way? When opening the software centre or opening any system services the local admin 's credentials are required. Any way to bypass this?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].